# swift 2 NSURLSessionDownloadTask completes even when there are still files left to be downloaded

Tags: ios, swift2, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am trying to download 30+ images using NSURLSessionDownloadTask, the problem is that it won't finish downloading everything. Sometimes, only 26 images are download but other times it is more or less. I've checked my url's and all of them exist but I don't understand why it's doing this. I have tried downloading using the json urls directly from the server and it crashes because of an empty optional which is caused I think by a connection timeout. I understand that happens because the internet here is not that stable. But when I tried to download the whole json file and saved it in my document directory and tried to download using the json that is saved locally, it doesn't crash anymore since I won't need to get the urls from the server. However, what happens is that my progress bar completes but not all images are downloaded. It's like the other urls are being ignored.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

var taskProgress = [NSURL: (written: Int64, expected: Int64)]()

@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressCount: UILabel!

var images = [String]()

var task : NSURLSessionTask!

var pics = ["http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/banner.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Abad-Edmerl.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Abellana-Deniz-Dawn-1.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Abequibel-Arneth.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Abilla-Harriette.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Pasko-Maria-Katrina.jpg", "http://pillar.foundationu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Pastias-Grace.jpg"]

var counter:Float = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        let fractionalProgress = Float(counter) / 100.0
        let animated = counter != 0

        progressBar.setProgress(fractionalProgress, animated: animated)
        progressCount.text = ("\(counter)%")
    }
    //The didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored. The fractionalProgress constant keeps track of the progress.
}

lazy var session : NSURLSession = {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    config.allowsCellularAccess = false
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    return session
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)  //set progressBar to 0 at  
start


}

@IBAction func doElaborateHTTP (sender:AnyObject!) {

    progressCount.text = "0%"
    if self.task != nil {
        return
    }


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let taskID = self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        let file = FileHelperClass()

        var url = NSURL!()
        var req = NSMutableURLRequest()

        var task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask!

        for s in file.parseJsonFromFile() /* fund returning images url */ {
            let url = NSURL(string: s)
            req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
            task = self.session.downloadTaskWithRequest(req)
            self.task = task
            task.resume()

        }

        // Do something with the result

   self.endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)

    })

}

func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten writ: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.taskProgress[downloadTask.originalRequest!.URL!] = (writ, exp)

        // Update your views, you may separate it into a different function
        let totalWritten = self.taskProgress.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1.written }
        let totalExpected = self.taskProgress.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1.expected }
        let progress = Float(totalWritten) / Float(totalExpected)

        self.progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        self.progressCount.text = "\(progress * 100)%"
    }
}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask:   
NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, 
expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
    // unused in this example
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, 
didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
//        print("completed: error: \(error)")
}

// this is the only required NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate method

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: 
NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
//        print(downloadTask.response!.suggestedFilename!)
    images.append(downloadTask.response!.suggestedFilename!)
    print("\n \(images)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it callback with any errors?

Comment: No errors at all cause it worked with few images but not with many images.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with obtaining the JSON data from the server, rather than with the downloads.  Maybe you're getting only part of the JSON data before you parse it.  Try dumping the list of URLs you got from the server and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Also, there's a known bug in NSURLSession where if you start up too many download tasks in a background session at once, they'll misbehave.  I don't know what the limit is, but somebody did hit it in another SO post that I commented on a few months back.  You might try sticking them all into your own mutable array (backed by NSUserDefaults) and starting ten or fifteen tasks at once, then adding new tasks as they complete.

Comment: BTW, your title is really confusing.  A download task downloads a single image, not a bunch of them.  So a task will complete when each file finishes downloading.